# How to change blackboard bold fonts using mathspec?

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, mathspec, blackboard, mathbb

I’m using `unicode-math` to change my blackboard bold font to TeX Gyre Schola Math, but it interferes with `mathalpha` (I use this to change my `cal`, `scr`, and `frak` fonts) and causes the positions of subscripts and superscripts in math equations to be slightly off. Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[range = bb, Scale = MatchUppercase]
```

If I use `mathspec`, my problems are solved but the font is not the blackboard bold of TeX Gyre Schola Math:

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathbb{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
```

What is the correct way to do this in `mathspec`?

Edit: I am using XeLaTeX by the way. Basically, my question is how to set the blackboard bold font to the blackboard bold font of TeX Gyre Schola Math specifically using `mathspec`?

Comment: Right now, it's not easy to interpret your claim that "the positions of subscripts and superscripts in equations are affected". Pleease extend your code snippets to make them compilable and make them exhibit the problem behavior you wish to fix. Please also indicate whether you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: it would be better to use unicode-math and fix whatever issue you had there, but the question isn't clear enough on those issues to suggest anything